# The number of distinct walks of minimum cost between two vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph

I just need an idea for how to find all the minimum cost walks between two vertices in a weighed directed graph. I don't know any algorithm that does that. I was thinking of using and algorithm for finding the walk with the lowest cost, then modify the weights of the vertices such that if i run it again it will be forced to give me another path next time. However this won't work if the new walk uses the edges that will be modified.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem this might help

Comment: What's wrong with BFS?

Comment: have you looked at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Comment: I don't want the shortest paths for every two vertices in the graph, I want the number (or the actual paths) of shortest paths between two given vertices, if there are more, or 1 if there is only one or no path if there isn't a path between them.

Comment: Take the algorithm to find the  walk with the lowest cost and change the termination condition. do not stop after finding one, but continue until you find one which is more expensive.

Comment: @Beta: It doesn't find shortest paths in a weighted graph? Maybe you meant Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your favorite shortest path algo and modify the relax operation so that it updates the number of shortest paths to the target node:

```
# initialization
count(src) = 1
dis(src) = 0
dis(v) = infinity forall v != src

relax(e = (v,w,c)):
  cdis = dis(v) + c
  if cdis < dis(w):
    dis(w) = cdis
    count(w) = count(v)
  else if cdis == dis(w)
    count(w) += count(v)
```

At the end of the algorithm, `count(dst)` will be the number of paths from the source to `dst`.

Obviously in the presence of zero-weight cycles, you have to consider the special case where there are infinitely many different paths between the vertices.

Comment: @Jelly: Watch out if there are non-positive cycles in the graph.